# Ionic App Version

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I can't install ionic native App Version.

When I write "**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version**" shows next message:

How can I fix it??

```
λ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version --save
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version --save (exit code 1):


    Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-app-version via registry.
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963229 Error output:
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Xu\Documents\github\rheumaiq_app\node_modules\es6-promise-plugin\package.json
    npm ERR! code ELOOP
    npm ERR! errno -4067
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open
    'C:\Users\Xu\Documents\github\rheumaiq_app\node_modules\es6-promise-plugin\package.json'

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Xu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-18T14_44_39_797Z-debug.log
```

UPDATE:

Thanks a lot!!

But the problem is not App Version, is with es6-promise-plugin in node_modules.

package.json

```
...
 "es6-promise-plugin": "file:node_modules/es6-promise-plugin",
...
```

this folder is empty, I dont know what I have to do.

Comment: Can you install other plugins from ionic0native? By the way, sometimes I get this type of error, but then it starts to work. Seems that npm server sometimes get down.

Comment: the command you pasted works great for me.  npm 5.4.2, ionic 3.13.1, cordova 7.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo
Here is how it should be

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appversion
```

Your mistake most likely results from the github repo being

```
https://github.com/Rareloop/cordova-plugin-app-version
```

But npm version name differs from the git repo name.

Comment: I've tried but doesn't work. show next error: https://pastebin.com/SdKM5QpU

Comment: Do you have the latest cordova? The vendor says to make sure the latest is installed if you have troubles. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appversion

Answer (score 1):

You can try cordovas `--nofetch` option to work around problems like this since cordova 7.0.0:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appversion --nofetch
```

See the release notes for cordova 7.0.0 [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html) to read more about the `--nofetch` mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it is empty, the problem is that it is a symbolic link that points to itself and therefore does not work. A loop is created.

If you delete the folder *node_modules/es6-promise-plugin* you will see that it is created again each time you type **npm install**...

I have seen this efect occurs adding the android platform, when try to do it for the cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing plugin, with the 5.2.1 version.

With the v5.2.0 that does not happen.

You can change your version:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing --force
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@5.2.0 --force
```

Or you can change in your package.json the version to use.